# Can not install simultaneusly gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly:i386 and gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly

Tags: package-management, wine

Apparently in order to play a game with wine I need both gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly:i386 and gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly

Trying to install them with aptitude reveals a conflict between libsidplay1v5 and libsidplay1v5:i386

So I cannot install both at once.
Is there any solution to this?

I am a very unexperienced ubuntu user, actually I needed help to realize I needed those 2 scripts to run the game in wine. So low level explanations will be appreciated.

Comment: Why would a game running under wine need gstreamer?

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libsidplay/+bug/1621861), which has been fixed in bionic.

I built libsidplay in a PPA:

https://launchpad.net/~gunnarhj/+archive/ubuntu/libsidplay

So if on xenial or artful you can solve it by opening a terminal window and running these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gunnarhj/libsidplay
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly:i386
```

Comment: Thanks, I just tried that but the wine program keeps crashing

Comment: @loBandolerPi: Then the cause was maybe something else but what you thought (or an additional cause). Anyway, thanks for triggering me to help with that bug. :)

Comment: @loBandolerPi Right, see my comment above. Why do you think you need this bit of gstreamer for a game running under wine?

Comment: @dobey: Please note that the reporter of the bug I linked to thinks the same.

Comment: If it's for MP3 support, would it not be better to install `gstreamer1.0-fluendo-mp3:i386` instead? It does not have such a conflict.